# Put two different dates in where statement

Tags: sql, database, date, where-clause

I would like to query the data of two specific months in a SQl statement.
These are December from last year and January from this year. This needs to be done in the where part of the SQL statement. (example Dec. 22 and Jan. 23)
Currently I am trying it like this:

```
...
SELECT month, year, [...] from table 
WHERE other condition
AND year IN ('2022', '2023')
AND month IN ('12', '1')
...
```

But with this I'm getting the December and January data from 2022 and 2023.
How can I solve this that I get just the January data from 2023 and the December data from 2022?

Comment: You will get January 2022 and 2023, and also December 2022 and 2023. Is that what you want?

Comment: I just want January 2023 and December 2022

Comment: Are you using MySQL specifically?

Comment: Why are you storing month and year as strings? Wouldn't `year in (2022, 2023)` do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get January 2023 and December 2022:

```
SELECT month, year, [...] from table 
WHERE other condition
  AND (year = '2023' and month = '1'
    OR year = '2022' and month = '12')
```

Or, if supported:

```
SELECT month, year, [...] from table 
WHERE other condition
  AND (year, month) IN (('2023', '1'), ('2022', '12'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT month, year, [...] from table
WHERE other condition
AND (year * 100 + month) >= 202212
AND (year * 100 + month) <= 202301
```

Comment: For non-numeric data type just do the conversion :)

Comment: This selects a range, while the OP may want to select distinct months. Anyway, for the provided sample dates there is no difference